# How to query on view count of Reports in salesforce?

Tags: reports-api

I want to delete reports automatically if it's not used in last  60 days
Is this possible?
I cannot find any of the fields which will give me the report view count in Reports metadata? [Report Metadata Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_list_resource.htm)